# Flyback transformer for offline switcher ac-dc PSU

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I am designing a 5V 3A SMPS circuit using Viper22a (60 kHz switching frequency) and transformer design is turning out to be the most difficult part of it. Actual load will draw less than 10 watts but I chose to go for 15 W just to be on the safer side. (Let me know if I am making a mistake here)

I referred to [AN4140 by Fairchild](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-4140.pdf) for quick core selection. In 10-20 watts section, it suggests these cores: EI22, EE19 and EPC19.

Then I talked to my local vendors about availability and I could find EE19, EPC17 and EFD20. I was able to find a [Flyback Transformer design tool](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/FLYBACK%20TRANSFORMER%20DESIGN%20TOOL.XLS) by ONsemi and I gave it a go for the suggested core and available cores. Tool looks like this:

[image: Flyback design tool]

Core data and calculated data according this sheet for various cores are as follows: (the only change required in excel sheet was core area Ae for different cores)

[image: Calculations]

Yellow ones were suggested in AN4140 and white ones are what I am planning to go with. EE19 is suggested as well as available but I am rejecting it due to height considerations.

I do not have much experience with magnetics design so would like to get my calculations verified by someone who knows this stuff better than me.

I have these questions as well:

1) Which core will be more suited - EPC17 or EFD20?

2) Minimum secondary turns is coming out as 12-15. What turn count should I actually go with? Is double of what I am getting good enough? Ex - 24-30 turns.

Please suggest any other improvements that I can implement.

Comment: If you double the number of secondary turns as you suggest, you get twice the reflected (flyback) voltage on top of your input voltage which your MOSFET must handle. Calculate your voltage stress for maximum input voltage and worst case leakage inductance.

Comment: @winny I think it is the other way around. Double the secondary turns, halve the flyback voltage.

Comment: My guess is to stay close to the recommended minimum secondary turns. The duty cycle you have chosen is already 0.3 (less than 50%), increasing the secondary turns would make that lower, you want to have a reason to do that.

Comment: No, you and are oversimplifying it. All equation holds true at the same time and you need to _carefully_ balance then. Use the preferred minimum number and calculate the voltage stress.

Comment: @Rioraxe - I deliberately took 0.3 because at higher values, I was getting very few turns. It appeared weird to have just 4-5 turns. Also, setting it lower means lower rms current through primary which appeared as a benefit to me. However I might be wrong. What's your opinion on this? Is it okay to go with very few number of turns? I read somewhere that secondary offers some sort of shielding and helps reduce EMI. Few turns means poor shielding.

Comment: @Winny - Sorry for my lack of knowledge/experience in this field but could you please suggest how to test for maximum voltage stress? I have a couple of multimeters and an oscilloscope. I am comfortable with working with ac and understand the precautions that I need to take.

Comment: No problem! Flybacks are the "easiest" because only one switch element, one diode and all your magnetics lumped into one transformer but also one of the most challanging to balance since everything affects everthing else. Your reflected flyback voltage is (Vout+Vdiode)*turn ratio. This is superimposed on top of your input voltage on the MOSFET. On top of that, you must select and balance your snubber network and again balance losses versus even more voltage stress. Your turn ratio will also set the voltage stress on your secondary diode, but diode voltage rating is cheap compared to MOSFET.

Comment: @winny - Thanks a lot. Your comments are proving to be very helpful. I found some relevant info in AN-4150 by fairchild. I found this equation: n = Np/Ns = Vro/(Vo1 + Vf1) : Vro = Reflected output voltage, Vo1 = Output voltage and Vf1 = diode drop. My calculations give me n = 10. That way, Vro = 60. Assuming 85-265V design, input voltage = 375V. Thus total voltage on mosfet = 375+60 = 435V. Mosfet is rated for 700V. 70% = 490V which is >435V. So I think this design is fine for the mosfet. Continued to next comment...

Comment: ... However, if I increase turns in secondary to lets say double, turn ratio becomes half. That way, I am getting 375+30 = 405V as compared to 435V in previous cases. Since I have a feedback control, so it's certain that my output voltage will remain at the setpoint which is 5V. So I think increasing the secondary turns is beneficial for the mosfet, as @rioraxe pointed out in his first comment. Let me know if I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Good. You are on the right track. You need to calculate and add snubber voltage on top of that and perhaps the capacitive spike too. As you increase the number of turns on the secondary, your peak voltage stress on your secondary diode increases but also the RMS current since it will be one short high bump in current instead of a slow and low one. If you plan for CCM, this will be a limitation.

Comment: I did some more reading to figure out what DCM and CCM is. Found a design note (www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/2-8.pdf) by infineon. After going through it, I concluded that DCM is easy to deal with and for 15W, I will be fine with this design. The note was easy to follow and for EPC17 (taking area = 22 mm^2), I got comparable results. Np = 117 and Ns = 9 (as compared to 152 and 15 from my original question). Should I go with these values, or do you suggest some changes to push the transformer to a safer side of design. I am using viper22a with integrated 700V mosfet.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Although I did look at the datasheet, I have not worked out much details. If the circuit will be in DCM like you said, the relationships are simpler. To deliver a certain amount power, \$ P = 0.5L{I_{peak}}^2 \times {freq} \$. The first term is the energy stored in the primary inductor per cycle. For fixed frequency and a specific power, \$I_{peak}\$ depends only on L (the inductance). It does not depend on the turn ratio.

Comment: Continued with fixed frequency and DCM. The duty cycle at low voltage and full load gives the limit of maximum switch on time. Once the components are set to that, the switch on time reduces with increasing input voltage, also reduces with decreasing load. The VIPer22A datasheet have a tONmin spec of 700ns. Presumably, if the switch on time has to go below that, it probably abandons the regulation in fixed frequency and goes into pulse skip mode. If you pick a low duty cycle to start with, with high voltage and light load, it is going to hit that limit sooner.

Comment: I have not winded a transformer for a long, long time. But I think one technique for low number of turns is to instead of using one thick wire, use a number of thinner wires in parallel such that you can wind the parallel wires in one complete layer.

Comment: @rioraxe - Thanks for making it clear. Right now I am planning to modify those parameters (like max duty cycle, turn ratio) a bit and place order for 4-5 different samples and test out the performance of each of them. I'll go with the one which delivers me enough power without things getting hot or turning into smoke.